# Search Flickr for all photos. What "tags" should be used?

Tags: search, tags, flickr

I want to search ALL Flickr photo base on location, what "tags" should be used?

I tried with NO "tag" specified, or "&tags=*", both return a seldom number of result! Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

If you have (or know how to get) latitude and longitude for your specific location, then have a look at [photosForLocation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation.html) and the [API explorer](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation) for this functionality.

Comment: I tried it on API explorer, "Insufficient permissions. Method requires read privileges; none granted." is returned!

Comment: You might want to go through the documentation. Especially on authorization and API keys.